Angularjs, how to format a oracle timestamp(6) to string without losing the last 3 digits?
AngularJS has a date filter, but it seems the accuracy can only down to milliseconds.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date
so for a oracle timestamp(6) which accuracy down to six decimal digit (e.g. 07-APR-20 12.37.00.795753000), how to format it in angularjs?
if using
{{i | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss'}}

only 2020-04-07 12:37:00.795
is shown.

[tag:angularjs] has been deprecated and completely out of support since December 31, 2021.  You should strongly consider using a more current, supported framework.  If you need more precision for the date filter supplied, you'll have to roll your own.

It seems JavaScript native date API supports only up to milliseconds.
So since everything is JavaScript is built on top of this API, it's not possible:
MDN Reference

It can't as per Angular.js documentation, there is support up to 'sss' there is no support for more than that, you need to create you own custom pipe for this.

Overview
Formats date to a string based on the requested format.
format string can be composed of the following elements:

'sss': Millisecond in second, padded (000-999)


